# Погодная станция на Raspberry PI 3 (python fix)

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Захотелось сделать погодную станцию на малинке... [Прочитал](https://www.hackster.io/4DMakers/raspberry-pi-internet-weather-station-f960c4), как всё настроить, но питон выдаёт ошибку.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Weather $ python weather.py
Warning: can't open ttyUSB0 serial port.
Driver: fbcon failed.
Driver: directfb failed.
Driver: svgalib failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weather.py", line 703, in <module>
    myDisp = SmDisplay()
  File "weather.py", line 98, in __init__
    raise Exception('No suitable video driver found!')
Exception: No suitable video driver found!
```

Сам код очень большой, поэтому посмотреть его можно только [**здесь**](http://www.instructables.com/files/orig/FAQ/7BWL/I1NULEIL/FAQ7BWLI1NULEIL.zip)

Comment: Экран на малинке это 4DPi35? Он отображает что-нибудь?

Comment: Нет, у меня xpt2046. Работает нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если написано:

```
Warning: can't open ttyUSB0 serial port.
```

То это означает, что либо устройство ttyUSB0 отсутствует в каталоге /dev,
либо, что у Вас нет прав на открытие этого устройства.

Сообщения:

```
Driver: fbcon failed.
Driver: directfb failed.
Driver: svgalib failed.
```

Говорят о том, что соответствующие пакеты не установлен в Вашей системе